# How do I keep every line from two tables, inserting nulls as appropriate

Tags: sql

I have two tables. One is called GradePeriods, which holds all the possible grading periods for each school in each year. The second is called Grades, which holds all of the grades given to each student in each school in each given year for each course he was enrolled in. Students do not always receive a grade in every possible grading period.

I want my result set to include all possible grading periods for each student's courses, inserting null values if the student wasn't given a grade during that grading period. It seems like this should be easy, but I can't get my head around how to do it. I've tried different kinds of joins, but none gives me the result set I want.

```
    CREATE TABLE GradePeriods
    ([Year] int, [School] varchar(5), [TermCode] varchar(2), [GradePeriod] varchar(10))
;
    
INSERT INTO GradePeriods
    ([Year], [School], [TermCode], [GradePeriod])
VALUES
    (2018, 'North', 'T1', 'Progress 1'),
    (2018, 'North', 'T1', 'T1 Final'),
    (2018, 'North', 'T2', 'Progress 2'),
    (2018, 'North', 'T2', 'T2 Final'),
    (2018, 'North', 'T3', 'Progress 3'),
    (2018, 'North', 'T3', 'T3 Final'),
    (2018, 'West', 'S1', 'Progress 1'),
    (2018, 'West', 'S1', 'Progress 2'),
    (2018, 'West', 'S1', 'S1 Final'),
    (2018, 'West', 'S2', 'Progress 3'),
    (2018, 'West', 'S2', 'Progress 4'),
    (2018, 'West', 'S2', 'S2 Final')
;
    
CREATE TABLE Grades
    ([Year] int, [School] varchar(5), [Student] int, [TermCode] varchar(2), [GradePeriod] varchar(10), [Course] varchar(7), [Grade] varchar(1))
;
    
INSERT INTO Grades
    ([Year], [School], [Student], [TermCode], [GradePeriod], [Course], [Grade])
VALUES
    (2018, 'North', 1, 'T1', 'Progress 1', 'English', 'B'),
    (2018, 'North', 1, 'T1', 'T1 Final', 'English', 'B'),
    (2018, 'North', 1, 'T1', 'Progress 1', 'Math', 'A'),
    (2018, 'North', 1, 'T2', 'T2 Final', 'History', 'A'),
    (2018, 'West', 2, 'S1', 'Progress 1', 'History', 'C'),
    (2018, 'West', 2, 'S1', 'Progress 2', 'History', 'D'),
    (2018, 'West', 2, 'S1', 'S1 Final', 'History', 'C'),
    (2018, 'West', 2, 'S2', 'Progress 3', 'Math', 'A'),
    (2018, 'West', 2, 'S2', 'S2 Final', 'Math', 'A')
;
```

This is the result set I'm trying to get:

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5abb6/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you build the list for each course and student.

Then, you build the list of expected grade period for each course and student.

Lastly, you left outer join the above with known grade,

this will give you the result you want with null values when grade is missing for the student in that course's grading period.

See the follow query as example:

```
WITH student_course_reg AS (
SELECT    
    DISTINCT
    YEAR,
    SCHOOL,
    TERMCODE,
    COURSE,
    STUDENT
FROM
    GRADES
),
expected_student_grade_period AS (
SELECT
  gp.Year,
  gp.school,
  gp.termcode,
  gp.gradeperiod,
  r.course,
  r.student
FROM
   student_course_reg r
JOIN
   GradePeriods gp
ON
  r.YEAR = gp.YEAR
  AND r.school = gp.school
  AND r.termcode = gp.termcode
)
SELECT
  e.YEAR,
  e.school,
  e.termcode,
  e.gradeperiod,
  e.course,
  e.student,
  g.grade
FROM
   expected_student_grade_period e
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   grades g
ON
  e.YEAR = g.YEAR
  AND e.school = g.school
  AND e.termcode = g.termcode
  AND e.gradeperiod = g.gradeperiod
  AND e.course = g.course
  AND e.student = g.student
ORDER BY
  e.YEAR,
  e.school,
  e.termcode,
  e.course,
  e.student,
  e.gradeperiod
```

[sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5abb6/21)
[image]